# array_filter returning unexpected results

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [pizza] => Calzone
        [votes] => 1
        [id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [pizza] => Margherita
        [votes] => 5
        [id] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [pizza] => Pepperoni
        [votes] => 9
        [id] => 3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [pizza] => Quattro Formaggi
        [votes] => 3
        [id] => 4
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [pizza] => Sloppy Giuseppe
        [votes] => 7
        [id] => 5
    )

)
```

And when I do this:

```
function getPizza () {
    $id = 3;

    return array_filter($myArrayAsAbove, function ($arr) use ($id) {
        return ($arr['id'] == $id);
    });
}
```

I get this:

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [pizza] => Pepperoni
        [votes] => 9
        [id] => 3
    )
```

Which I'm sure is correct, but really I'd like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [pizza] => Pepperoni
        [votes] => 9
        [id] => 3
    )
```

Notice the `0` instead of the `2`.

Could someone help me find a solution and if you're really nice, explain a little bit about why this is happening, and how it can be fixed - so I'll know for next time!

Comment: It happens because as the [`array_filter` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) say, array keys are preserved. Since Pepperoni had key 2 in the original matrix, it keeps that key in the returned matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_filter` keeps the array keys. If you don't want them, `array_values` gives you only the values "wrapped in a new array":

```
return array_values(array_filter($pizzen, function ($arr) use ($id) {
    return $arr['id'] == $id;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for array_filter() specifically says:

> Array keys are preserved.

If you want to reset the keys, use something like array_merge() as well

```
function getPizza () { 
    $id = 3; 

    return array_merge(array_filter($myArrayAsAbove, function ($arr) use ($id) { 
        return ($arr['id'] == $id); 
    })); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getPizza () { 
    $id = 3; 

    return array_values(array_filter($myArrayAsAbove, function ($arr) use ($id) { 
        return ($arr['id'] == $id)); 
    })); 
}
```

[`array_values`](http://php.net/array-values) re-indexes the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_values()` to recreate the indexes:

```
return array_values(array_filter($myArrayAsAbove, function ($arr) use ($id) {
    return ($arr['id'] == $id);
}));
```